# Is it possible to get wallet balance passing the wallet address on any cryptocurrency?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I want to know that if exists a generic api that I put a wallet address, and it returns the balance of this wallet, or if each cryptocurrency offers an api to do it? Or it's not possible? As far as I know, see the balance of one wallet is public, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ethereum the API is called [web3.eth.getBalance](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance).

There is no generic solution because each blockchain uses its own incompatible wallet technology.

Comment: Got it. Do you know if the most popular cryptocurrancies has api for this? Bitcoin, Tezos, Monero, etc?!

Comment: Yes, all blockchains have API to query the wallet balance. For each blockchain, you need to figure out how.